# NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification sent only one time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my app I set up an `NSFileHandle` to (try to) read a file when it is updated.  However, I receive only one notification, the first time the file is modified.  The `waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify` is called from a subclass of `NSApplication`, so there is an active runloop.  The only issue I can think that might affect this is that the process that writes the file uses `NSDictionary` `writeToFile` with `atomically:true`.  Is this a problem?
Am I missing something else?

FWIW, I can replace the notification with a timer in the runloop and read the file that way.  Sort of defeats the purpose of the callbacks...

Setting up the fileHandle

```
- (void)setupRead:(id)sender
{
    self.fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/path/to/some/file.xml"];
    if( self.fileHandle == nil )
    {
        [self.taskLabel setStringValue:@"Error:"];
        [self.taskText setStringValue:@"Unable to connect to status file"];
        return;
    }

    // register for notifications
    [self.fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(readData:) name:NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification object:nil];
}
```

The read callback

```
- (void)readData:(NSNotification*)note
{
    NSData* msg = [self.fileHandle availableData];
    if( [msg length] )
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        NSDictionary* statusDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:msg options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil error:&error];
        [self displayStatus:statusDictionary];
    }    
    [self.fileHandle waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried writing non-atomically? I've done something similar in the past and that was the issue.

Comment: Even if write is not atomic (atomic = write to tmp then replace file, nonatomic = truncate and write), `availableData` reads to end of file, so there is no need for file handle to stay open. If outer process will do non-atomic write, fh's read position aka seek is not zero anyway, so you can't "just read again" without rewind.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the writer, so changing to non-atomic writes would be problematic at best.  I did try adding seekToFileOffset, but received the same data for each read.  That is, I received the NSFileHandleDataAvailableNotification, but the data was always the same as the initial data.  Interesting.  It seems that I receive the notification from the 'new' file while getting the data from the 'old'.